# How to pass multiple condition to find function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to pass multiple conditions to Jquery find function
e.g

```
$(selector).find("input[type='text',id='txtId']") //this is not a right way
```

what is the solution?

Comment: Why would you need a type='text' clause when you have the id?  In fact why would you use .find() if you have the id?

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to do it is like this:

```
$("#txtId")
```

Why? Because you can only have one thing with that id, and therefore there is no need to use `find`. But maybe you could come up with a better example of what you are trying to do. It seems like I'm missing something here :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find you answer here http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

The docs say jQuery('[attributeFilter1][attributeFilter2][attributeFilterN]'). Anyway, if you try to select `<input type="text" id="id1" class="cls1"/>` by id and class, this is the way:

```
$('input#id1.cls1')
```